# Toggle Increment and decrement count on single element click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a element which has an integer count.

`<span class="likes-count"> 2 </span>`

And a div when clicked have to toggle the increment and decrement of the value.
`<div class="liked"></div>`

**Problem:** 
I have called a function on `$('.liked').clicked` which increments the value and changes the class to `.notliked` 
And another onclick function decrements the value, but it's not working properly.
Please review my code. I guess this is not the best way to do this.

Here's my demo code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".notliked").click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.removeClass('notliked');
        $this.addClass('liked')
        $count = $('.likes-count');
        $count.html((parseInt($count.html(),10) || 0) + 1);

    });

    $(".liked").click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.removeClass('liked');
        $this.addClass('notliked');
        $count = $('.likes-count');
        $count.html((parseInt($count.html(),10) || 0) - 1); 

    });        
});
```

```css
.heart {
  color: #fff;
  height:50px;
  cursor:pointer;
  width:50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="likes-count"> 2 </span>

<div class="liked heart">Click</div>
```

Comment: might want to use `.toggleClass()` for this instead - http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: I tried that. It didn't work for my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to delegate the click event. At the beginning **$(".notliked")** returns 0 elements and so it's never executed.

In order to increment/decrement the text value you can use:

[.text( function )](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) like:

```
$count.text(function(idx, txt) {
   // convert text to number and increment by one
   return +txt + 1;
});
```

The snippet:

```js
$(document).on('click', ".notliked", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.removeClass('notliked');
    $this.addClass('liked')
    $count = $('.likes-count');
    $count.text(function(idx, txt) {
      return +txt + 1;
    });

});

$(document).on('click', ".liked", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.removeClass('liked');
    $this.addClass('notliked');
    $count = $('.likes-count');
    $count.text(function(idx, txt) {
      return (+txt == 0) ? 0 : (+txt - 1);
    });

});
```

```css
.heart {
color: #fff;
height:50px;
cursor:pointer;
width:50px;
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<span class="likes-count"> 0 </span>

<div class="liked heart">Click</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. It's working. One more question. If the initial count is 0, I don't want to decrement it to -1. Can you please tell me how to achieve that :)